# WCF security, changing the WindowsIdentity from inside a service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have a client app that calls a WCF service on a different server

in the service I print out the following:
1. ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
2. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

1 above gives me my windows login and 2 gives me the windows login that the server is logged in as

How can i change 2 so that it gives me my windows login (not the login of the server)? Is there a way to force it?

i want to do this because in the WCF service i need to call another service with my original windows login credentials

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links about impersonating the caller's identity in a WCF service - that'll be what you have to do, basically:

- [WCF security guidance - How To Impersonate the original caller](https://web.archive.org/web/20080612180823/http://www.codeplex.com:80/WCFSecurity/Wiki/View.aspx?title=How%20To%20-%20Impersonate%20the%20Original%20Caller%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=How%20Tos)
- [Delegation and Impersonation with WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/delegation-and-impersonation-with-wcf)
- [Setting up WCF to Impersonate Client credentials](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122071525/http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2009/04/23/setting-up-wcf-to-impersonate-client-credentials.aspx)
- [Caller impersonation for WCF services](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113233725/http://www.wintellect.com:80/CS/blogs/pmehner/archive/2007/12/16/caller-impersonation-for-wcf-services-hosted-under-iis-is-broken.aspx)

Marc